# using modal popup for php redirect

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog

I have a php mail form (working fine) that currently redirects to a thank you page. I am revamping the site and would like to (instead of redirecting to another page) have (upon successful submit) a modal popup appear and say thank you. I would also need to have the form cleared since the user would be staying on the current page. I have searched (both on stackoverflow and web searches) for a solution. I have found a few "ideas" but nothing that has worked. I am currently using modal popups on other things on the site (since revamp) and generally understand how they work. I also have a basic understanding of php. I was thinking if its possible(?) to have some type of javascript in header to invoke the modal popup. I've also seen ideas of it needing to be AJAX.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my html for form:

```
<p class="formrequired">Required fields are marked with an asterisk(*)</p>
<form action="form.php" method="post">
    <ol class="forms">
    <li><label for="first_name">*First Name</label><input type="text" name="first_name"/></li>
    <li><label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input type="text" name="last_name"/></li>
    <li><label for="email">*Email</label><input type="text" name="email"/></li>
    <li><label for="comment">*Message</label><textarea name="comment"cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></li>
    <li><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"/> 
    </ol>
</form>
```

and my php:

```
<?php

$myemail  = "person@email.com";

$first_name = check_input($_POST['first_name'], "Please enter your first name");
$last_name  = check_input($_POST['last_name']);
$email      = check_input($_POST['email']);
$comment    = check_input($_POST['comment'], "Please enter your message");


if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
    show_error("E-mail address is not a valid email address");
}

$subject="New form submitted on Napoleonville Fire";

$message = "Hello Jordy!

Your contact form has been submitted by:

First Name: $first_name
Last Name: $last_name

E-mail: $email

They left the following message:

$comment

End of message.
";

mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

header('Location: thankyou.html');
exit();


function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
    <html>
    <body>

    <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
    <?php echo $myError; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
<?php
exit();
}


?>
```

Again, thanks for any and all help.

I will have a "part 2" if this can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Two flows I can think of

**Non-AJAX**

Submit your form to the server as you currently do.  Then when redering the success page, render the page with the modal showing.  Provide a close button of some sort that set's display none on it or deletes it from the DOM altogether.  In this approach you can handle rendering the empty form with PHP.  This is the more traditional paradigm.

**AJAX**

For this, add an event handler to the form submission.  Submit the form via AJAX, but don't immediately clear the form fields.  Wait for the response from the server.  If the server finds a validation error in the form submission for example you will have to update the form to reflect this error.  If the server returns a success response, clear the form fields with Javascript and show the modal.

Comment: Hopefully that's somewhat helpful, but it's very general!

Comment: I (think at least) I am understanding what you are talking about in the non-ajax way. After successful submit (using header on php) show the same page but add in the modal pop up box? this will also have the form cleared since I'm just reshowing the original page. With the ajax way I'm not real sure on how to accomplish that. I'm thinking (bc of) part 2 of my question that I may need to use the ajax way.

Comment: Yes, I would say if you're not very familiar with AJAX, the first approach would be much easier to grasp and implement.  You just display the modal when the page reloads if the form validated successfully and the mail was sent, and provide a simple JS click handler so that they can have a close button on the modal.

Comment: Alright, I think I'm understanding the non-ajax way (at least hope lol) my part 2 (which was why I was thinking ajax) was to have in case of an error in the data entered) was to have a modal popup stating the error instead of currently showing it through the php page. I've been spending countless hours studying ajax and jquery more in depth and I think I have the "flow" down now just not completely sure on the coding itself...